# Set-theory confusing a bit

Tags: real-analysis

> 2 subsets of $\mathbb R $ are given:
>
> $(0,\frac{2}{e}), (0,+\infty)$
>
> • Find $A$, where $A=B\cup C.$ Where, $B=(0,\frac{2}{e}),C= (0,+\infty)=\mathbb R^*_+$.

**Personal work:**

Well, $$(0,\frac{2}{e})\in\mathbb R^*_+$$ but that means that $B$ is basically $C-\frac{2}{e}$ so, $A=B=\mathbb R^*_+-\frac{2}{e}\Rightarrow A=B \cup C=\mathbb R^*_+-\frac{2}{e}$. Is this correct?

Comment: Your first displayed equation is incorrect as written: the elements of $\mathbb{R}^*_+$ are real numbers, but your left hand side is a set of real numbers; $\mathbb{R}^*_+$ does not contain intervals as elements.

Comment: No: $B$ is all positive real numbers $x$ that are smaller than $\frac{2}{e}$; $C$ is all positive real numbers. $A$ is supposed to be the union of $B$ and $C$, that is, all elements that are in either $B$ or $C$. So: what are the elements that are in either $B$ or in $C$? It’s not what you describe. Also: “$\mathbb{R}_+^* - \frac{2}{e}$” is also nonsense as written: $\mathbb{R}_+^*$ is a set, $\frac{2}{e}$ is a real number. You can’t subtract a real number from a set. You can either subtract real numbers from real numbers, or sets from sets.

Comment: $B$ is a subset of $C$, so $A=C$.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it:

$B = (0, \frac 2e) = \{x\in \mathbb R| 0 < x < \frac 2e\}$.

$C = (0, +\infty) = \{x \in \mathbb R| 0 < x\}$.

So $A = B \cup C = \{x \in \mathbb R| 0 < x < \frac 2e$ or $0 < x\}$.

The statement $0 < x < \frac 2e$ is conjunction of two statements i) $0 < x$ and ii) $x < \frac 2e$ so we want:  $(0 < x$ and $x < \frac 2e)$ or $(0< x)$

So you have a conjunction of two statements; (i and ii) or (i)$

If i) is false then "(i and ii)" is false and "(i and ii) or (i)" is false.  So i) may not be false (whether or not ii) is true of false).

If i) is true then "(i)" is true and "(i and ii) of (i)" is true whether or not (ii) is false.

So the upshot is "(i and ii) or (i)" is true iff and only if i) is true.

So

$A = B \cup C = \{x \in \mathbb R| 0 < x < \frac 2e$ or $0 < x\}=\{x \in \mathbb R| 0< x\} = (0, +\infty)$

... that's it.

Now, to critique your work:

"but that means that $B$ is basically $C−\frac 2e$."

Well, no....  $1 > \frac 2e$ so $1 \not \in B$ but $1 \in C$ so $\frac 2e$ is not the only thing that needs to be removed from $C$. $1$ must be removed from $C$ as well.  And $2,3,4,5,6.... > \frac 2e$ must also be removed from $C$.  And for *any* $y \ge \frac 2e$ then $y$ must be removed.  SO the *ENTIRE* $[\frac 2e,+\infty)$ must be removed from $C$.

But if you are comfortable with the notation: you can say $B = C$ setminus $[\frac 2e, +\infty)$.

And $C$ setminus $[\frac 2e, +\infty)= $

$\{x\in C|$ it is not that case that $x \ge \frac 2e\} = $

$\{x\in C| x < \frac 2e\} = $

$C \cap \{x\in \mathbb R|x < \frac 2e\} = $

$\{x\in \mathbb R|x > 0\} \cap  \{x\in \mathbb R|x < \frac 2e\}=$

$\{x\in \mathbb R|x > 0$ and $x < \frac 2e\}=$

$\{x \in \mathbb R|0 < x < \frac 2e\} = (0, \frac 2c\}$.

"so, A=B=R∗+−2e⇒A=B∪C=R∗+−2e."

What.... I can't.... follow at all.  You believe $B = C - $ a point so $A = B \cup C = $ ..... $B$????  How on earth does that follow? and form that you get that $B$ equals all of $\mathbb R$ minus a point????  I.... don't get it.

====  OR THE MIND BOGGLING OBVIOUS WAY TO DO IT =====

If $X \subset Y$ then $Z = X\cup Y = Y$.

So $B= (0, \frac 2e) \subset (0, +\infty) = C$.

So $A = B \cup C = C$.